# Making an active element and making the rest unactive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a link active and the rest unactive at the same time. It works but i would like to ask if there is any better way to do it? Because if there would be more elements i would have to write many more same lines of code. I know there is pseudo element :checked but i guess it only works for checkboxes and radios.

```js
const first = document.querySelector('.first');
const second = document.querySelector('.second');
const third = document.querySelector('.third');

first.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  first.classList.add('active');
  second.classList.remove('active');
  third.classList.remove('active');
})

second.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  second.classList.add('active');
  first.classList.remove('active');
  third.classList.remove('active');
})

third.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  third.classList.add('active');
  second.classList.remove('active');
  first.classList.remove('active');
})
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
}

ul a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first.active{
  color: hsl(220, 98%, 61%);
}

.second.active{
  color: hsl(220, 98%, 61%);
}

.third.active{
  color: hsl(220, 98%, 61%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link first">Link1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link second">Link2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link third">Link3</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about a loop something like

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".first, .second, .third");

list.forEach(element => element.addEventListener(
    'click', () => {
        list.foreach(e2 => e2.classList.remove('active'));
        element.classList.add('active');
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to handle toggling an element, which would make more sense than adding new code for every event listener. Your event listener could then include the event as well, so you can keep track of which element was clicked.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

const hideElement = (element) => {
  if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
  }
}

const showElement = (element) => {
  if (!element.classList.contains('active')) {
      element.classList.add('active');
  }
}

const handleClick = (event) => {
  let element = event.target;

  links.forEach(link => hideElement(link));

  showElement(element);
}

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    handleClick(event)
  })
});
```

```css
  body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
  }

  ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style:none;
  }

  ul li{
    margin: 0rem 1rem;
  }

  ul a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .link.active{
    color: hsl(220, 98%, 61%);
  }
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link3</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```